# how to add a TiltledBorder in a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, titled-border

I am trying to make an UI with Swing using only one `Container` with the `GridBagLayout` !

My problem is that I want to regroup some `JtextFields` and `Jlabels` under one title (`TitledBorder`) in my interface, is there a way to add the border directly in my container, or should I create another `JPanel` to regroup my components and then add the hole Panel to my `GridBagLayout` ?

Comment: You can do either approach, add the Border the main panel or add the Border to child panels. It depends on your exact requirement. Experiment and see what happens.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your answer, but i will explain more, i have multiple JLabels and JTextFields in different cells of my GridBagLayout, and i want to regroup all those cells under one TitledBorder, is that possible without Adding all my components to a new Jpanel and then adding it to my Main Container ?
P.s : i will have at least 3 regroupements like this in my UI !

Comment: `i will have at least 3 regroupements like this in my UI !` - Think about it. How do you add one TitledBorder to one panel when you have 3 groups?

Comment: @camickr so you are saying that iam obliged to create 3 panels with titled borders, and then affect them to my GridBagLayout container ?

Comment: That is what  I would do. I don't know of any other way.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us what you've tried.  What exactly do you mean by "regroup"?  I don't see how adding a TitledBorder to a JPanel would restrict in anyway the ability to layout its components, regardless of LayoutManager.  So, yes, you can do it.  Are you having a problem, or is this some kind of "best practices" question?

Comment: <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/BrmJo.png"></img>
@splungebob taking this UI for example, is there a way to put those titled borders (regroupements) using one only container (with GridBagLayout) ? or the only way is to create two other JPanels with titled borders and then affect them to my main container just like camickr said ?

Comment: Oh, I see now. If you want both the Name and Email "groups" to each have their own border, then I'd suggest 2 separate panels, each with it's own TitledBorder, then placing these 2 panels on a 3rd outer panel.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of TitledBorders, use a JLabel followed by a horizontal JSeparator for each group title.  This will give a similar "group separation" effect while allowing you to work with only one panel.

Comment: @splungebob that's exactely what i was looking for, thank you !

Comment: @MohamedZouga ok - I posted a more complete answer with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the pic you provided, the typical solution would be to have 2 separate panels, each with their own TitledBorder, and then place both of these panels on a third outer panel.

However, you could create a similar effect on a single panel by replacing the TitledBorders with a combination of a JLabel followed by a JSeparator.

The difference is that the logical "group" of fields is now only defined by title that isn't surrounding the whole group.  Some people prefer this, others do not.

Here's a sample of your pic to give you the idea:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test implements Runnable
{
  private JTextField firstName;
  private JTextField lastName;
  private JTextField title;
  private JTextField nickname;
  private JComboBox format;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Test());
  }

  public Test()
  {
    firstName = new JTextField(20);
    lastName = new JTextField(20);
    title = new JTextField(20);
    nickname = new JTextField(20);
    format = new JComboBox();
  }

  public void run()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(createPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private JPanel createPanel()
  {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(4,4,4,4);
    gbc.ipadx = 1;
    gbc.ipady = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    JLabel nameHeader = new JLabel("Name:");
    nameHeader.setForeground(Color.RED.darker());
    p.add(nameHeader, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    p.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    p.add(firstName, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    p.add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    p.add(lastName, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    p.add(new JLabel("Title"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    p.add(title, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    p.add(new JLabel("Nickname"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    p.add(nickname, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    p.add(new JLabel("Format"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    p.add(format, gbc);

    return p;
  }
}
```

You could play with the constraints to polish this up a bit, but you get the idea.

An upside to this approach is that when adding more fields for the Email section, you can get them to line up with the fields in the Name section.  With separate panels, this would be more difficult (you could use a bunch of Box.createHorizontalStrut(...) for this).

The downside to this approach is that you now have a large panel with many fields, and it could get a bit unwieldy to maintain if you need to add more fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class SwingLayoutDemo {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel statusLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JLabel msglabel;

public SwingLayoutDemo(){
   prepareGUI();
}

 public static void main(String[] args){
  SwingLayoutDemo swingLayoutDemo = new SwingLayoutDemo();  
  swingLayoutDemo.showGridBagLayoutDemo();       
}

  private void prepareGUI(){
  mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
  mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
  mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

  headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
  statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);        

  statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  controlPanel = new JPanel();
  controlPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder (
  new LineBorder (Color.black, 5),
  "Title String"));
  controlPanel.add(new JLabel("TitledBorder using LineBorder"));

  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
  mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
  }

  private void showGridBagLayoutDemo(){
  headerLabel.setText("Layout in action: GridBagLayout");      

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
  panel.setSize(300,300);
  GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();

  panel.setLayout(layout);        
  GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

  gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  gbc.gridx = 0;
  gbc.gridy = 0;
  panel.add(new JButton("Button 1"),gbc);

  gbc.gridx = 1;
  gbc.gridy = 0;
  panel.add(new JButton("Button 2"),gbc); 

  gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  gbc.ipady = 20;   
  gbc.gridx = 0;
  gbc.gridy = 1;
  panel.add(new JButton("Button 3"),gbc); 

  gbc.gridx = 1;
  gbc.gridy = 1;       
  panel.add(new JButton("Button 4"),gbc);  

  gbc.gridx = 0;
  gbc.gridy = 2;      
  gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  gbc.gridwidth = 2;
  panel.add(new JButton("Button 5"),gbc);  

  controlPanel.add(panel);

  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
 }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: First, thank you for your answer but this is the second way, it works i know, but i'am asked to introduce all my components in one and only one container, it would be easy if it wasn't for the TitledBorder :/ 
In other words, i have to introduce a TiltledBorder to a group of components Directly in my Only container that uses GridBagLayout !